# Python large list error

Tags: python, list

I did the following program to generate a list of consecutive numbers. However, the computations seem to fail for more than 70.000 elements in the list.  I tried using Pycharm IDE and also the python console. The result is the same. I'm using the Python 3.4.1 32-bit version. What should I do ? Which can be the cause ?

```
from pylab import *

a = 100000                    # the number of elements from my_array
my_array = [i for i in range(a)]

missing_number = randint(a)
print('Generate a Random number: ', missing_number)
my_array.remove(missing_number)   # We remove the random generated number from my_array
print('The number of elements of the list is: ', len(my_array))     #Length of  my_array
print('the sum of the list is :',sum(my_array))             # Sum

sum02 = (a *(a-1)/2)        #  The sum of consecutive numbers
print('The complete sum of the consecutive numbers:',int(sum02),'\n')
print('And the missing number is:', int(sum02) - sum(my_array))
```

---

I will reproduce the result that I have locally on my machine :

C:\Util\Python34\python.exe "find_missing_number_2.py"

```
Generate a Random number:  15019
The number of elements of the list is:  99999
the sum of the list is : 704967685
The complete sum of the consecutive numbers: 4999950000
And the missing number is: 4294982315
Process finished with exit code 0
```

It doesn't result an error. It's just doing wrong calculations as you can see
if you compare the two variables: 
**missing_number** with the one resulted from **int(sum02)-sum(my_array)**

Comment: Give us the result differences. What is right and what is wrong! With current information given, we cannot give you advices

Comment: Which is the error are you getting?

Comment: ​-1 can not reproduce

Comment: I have checked and found his problem is when using `sum(my_array)`, it returns wrong result for large number of a. ex: 70000

Comment: is there a good reason to store all your numbers ? with a data set that size I would have thought it would be better to use a database system.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 `xrange` takes care of that by using a generator. Under python3 `range` returns a generator by default.

Comment: @ReutSharabani i agree that in the specific case where all he is doing is suming and averaging a generated range of numbers - but i doubt that is the actually the detailed use case here.

Comment: Just a suggestion ... don't call the same function more than once with the same parameters.  Assign the value to a variable ... `sum1 = sum(my_array)`

Comment: I will reproduce my problem I've got:                        C:\Util\Python34\python.exe find_missing_number_2.py"
Generate a Random number:  15019
The number of elements of the list is:  99999
the sum of the list is : 704967685
The complete sum of the consecutive numbers: 4999950000 
And the missing number is: 4294982315
Process finished with exit code 0                                     It doesn't result an error. It's just doing wrong calculations as you can see if you compare the two variables: missing_number with the one resulted from int(sum02)-sum(my_array)

Answer (score 3):

`from pylab import *` does a `from numpy import *`. This includes the [numpy.sum](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) function which explicitly says that `Arithmetic is modular when using integer types, and no error is raised on overflow.`

To avoid this used the builtin sum function, either as shown by Reut Sharabani, or by not doing `from pylab import *`, which is a bad practice anyway. It can replace any built-in functions, without you noticing. As far as I know, it replaces at least sum and all at the moment, but I'm not sure that's all, and you can't be sure that it won't replace others in the future.

Comment: It also replaces min and max

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is the size of the list, try using [xrange](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange):

```
# my_array = [i for i in range(a)]
my_array = xrange(a)
```

Also, `my_array = [i for i in range(a)]` is the same as `my_array = range(a)` if you're using python 2.X

Edit: To use built-in `sum` (arbitrary percision):

```
__builtins__.sum(a)
```

Comment: Not really works! if I set a for 70000 and I call sum(myarray), it will return -1845002296 (same as range)

Comment: 70000 elements in a list should not be a problem.  Mentioning to use generators instead to save memory makes sense, but the problem here must be sth else.

Comment: **I'm using the Python 3.4.1**

Comment: With python3 you could use list(range(a)) instead

Answer (score 0):

How about creating your own function for summing consecutive numbers ...

```
def consecutive_sum(first, last):
    half = (first + last) / 2.0
    return half * (last - first + 1)
```

Then you don't need a list of numbers and you can just get one random number (e.g. n) and ...

```
sum1 = consecutive_sum(1, n-1)
sum2 = consecutive_sum(n+1, max_num)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found which was the cause.
 The cause was as mentioned by user2313067 the fact that I imported all the pylab module and some of its functions overlap over some others python built-in functions. Bad practice indeed to import all the module especially if you are using only a function.
So the solution is in this case :

```
from pylab import randint
```

and the code works even for very large lists (a = 10000000).
My result is now correct :

```
C:\Util\Python34\python.exe "find_missing_number_2.py"
Generate a Random number:  3632972
The number of elements of the list is:  9999999
the sum of the list is : 49999991367028
The complete sum of the consecutive numbers: 49999995000000 

And the missing number is: 3632972

Process finished with exit code 0
```